# What do I do if two people provided an answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I posted a question earlier and more than one person answered it correctly. I'm in a bit of a dilemma as to which to accept because they all provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up vote both and accept the one you like better. It's all up to you.